# Replace with regex (LATEX)

Tags: overleaf

Assume that we have a lot of commands like that:

```
\textlatin{bla bla bla}
```

I want to raplace
`\textlatin{bla bla bla} with raw "bla bla bla"`.

I used regex to find all `\textlatin{bla bla bla}` with `\\textlatin{[a-z-\ ]*}` but I can't find a manner to replace correctly.

Has anyone idea how to do it in **Overleaf**?

Comment: are you sure you want to use l3regex here? it does not have access to the document source, unless you have already grabbed a section as a command argument. Normally you would do the replacement in your editor, or simply `\renewcommand\textlatin[1]{#1}`

Comment: If you want to do this with the 'conventional' regex, you'll have to use capturing groups https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: In the latter case, the question isn't really on topic here... unless questions about using editor counts. By the way, don't use the l3regex tag if you don't really want to do it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't mean to use l3regex. I couldn't find any relevant tag for regex so I chose that one.

Comment: in that case what do you mean? do you want to edit and re-save your source file without `\textlatin` ? If so it is purely a question about your editor not really about latex, and you have not said what editor you are using

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Currently I am using overleaf, I edited the post. Can you tell me explicitly how to use \renewcommand\textlatin[1]{#1} ? Yes, I want to replace all the \textlatin(string) with raw string and save the source file.

Comment: if you add that to your document then `\textlatin` will still be there but will do nothing, that's easier perhaps than removing every instance

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is definitely not something you should recommend for someone who probably don't know what it does to add to their document. (not just because they might get more mysterious error messages later)

Comment: @user202729 well to be honest I think it is a safer thing to suggest than applying a global regex replace to the document source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more a question about code editors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

in overleaf ctrl-f will show a seach replace dialog as above

1. `[^{}]*` which matches any string without {} in the argument (this will not find `\textlatin{...\textbf{...}}` )
2. if you use `()` around the `[^{}]*` to capture the substring
3. You can use `$1` to use the substring as the replacement
4. Make sure you clicked the `.*` to get regex seach
5. click *All* and they should all be replaced

Comment: +1 for the artwork

Comment: @JosephWright I do have a tikz gold badge

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much. That is exactly what I need.

Comment: Sir, I hope you are teaching somewhere. If you do not, please start a Youtube channel where you recreate a good math or computer science book. Your answers have been invaluable and helped me improve my Latex skills. This answer is no different, but it also clarifies a confusing regex thing for me, which is the reason for using `()`, as not using it will still match the same string. For the book, I suggest *Introduction to Algorithms, CLRS*. It is a beautiful book.

Comment: If anyone of you is wondering why David Carlisle answer is not actually working, it is because he missed the `\` before the `{` and `}` symbols. The correct answer would be `\\textlatin\{(.*)\}`. Any special character needs the `\` before.

Comment: With the new Overleaf source environment, you would need to escape the curly braces (as proposed by a new user who is not yet able to comment).

Comment: @JasperHabicht fixed

Comment: @izzo1992 thanks, fixed